# How to transfer ETH between IMX users without transferring a token

Tags: javascript, nft

I want to transfer ETH that's on one IMX account to another IMX account. The transfer isn't bound to the transfer of any token. Just want to transfer ETH. How do I do that? I've found the concept of a Signable Transfer. https://docs.x.immutable.com/reference/post_v1-signable-transfer-details-1

And then the endpoint to create a transfer of tokens between parties.
https://docs.x.immutable.com/reference/post_v1-transfers-1

But there are a couple of problems:
For the second one I don't know where to get the values for some of the fields to be passed in the request, like `receiver_start_key`, `receiver_vault` (respective fields for sender) and `stark_signature`.

I suppose that I'd get those fields maybe from the `post_v1-signable-transfer-details-1` request. But I don't want to make a transfer based on the sale of a token. Just transfer amount.
I managed to get an example of what the request will look like from the IMX docs

```
  url: 'https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/signable-transfer-details',
  headers: {Accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  data: {
    amount: 'string',
    receiver: 'string',
    sender: 'string',
    token: {
      data: {decimals: 18, token_address: 'string', token_id: '200'},
      type: 'ETH/ERC20/ERC721'
    }
  }
```

But I don't know what I'm supposed to put in `data[token_address]` and `data[token_id]`

I don't even know if I'm approaching this problem properly or looking at the right place. but it's just a bit vague at the moment. So any help will be much welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Link SDK from Immutable instead https://docs.x.immutable.com/docs/linktransfer

```
const transferResponsePayload:TransferV2ResultsCodec = await link.transfer([
      {
        amount: '1.23',
        symbol: 'GODS',
        type: ERC20TokenType.ERC20,
        tokenAddress: '0x4c04c39fb6d2b356ae8b06c47843576e32a1963e',
        toAddress: 'replace-this-with-a-receiver-address',
      },
      {
        amount: '0.23',
        type: ETHTokenType.ETH,
        toAddress: 'replace-this-with-a-receiver-address',
      },
    ]);
```